# Data formats of inputs to arrange function in dplyr

Tags: r, function, types, dplyr

Given a table `monkeys` with column `brain_size`, one can write something like **`arrange(monkeys, brain_size)`**.

I don't understand how this makes sense -- **`brain_size` isn't a declared variable** (if I refer to it, I get an error). It's just the name of a column -- shouldn't you rather have `arrange(monkeys, 'brain_size')`? ***Isn't* the column name just a string?**

Another related weirdness --

```
arrange(monkeys, desc(brain_size))
```

Once again, what exactly is the **`desc` function**? How can it take `brain_size` as an input? Shouldn't you have something like `arrange(monkeys, 'brain_size', desc = true)`?

Am I missing something? Perhaps `brain_size` is a variable in some way but can only be accessed when you're unambiguously "inside" `monkeys`.

Comment: This is called tidy evaluation and is how most `dplyr` functions, and many functions in other tidyverse packages, is designed

Comment: Dplyr uses Non-Standard Evaluation, meaning the quoting is actually being done *within* the function call itself. I'd check out [this article](https://edwinth.github.io/blog/nse/).

Comment: It is non-standard evaluation or (NSE), and is used in several places in R (e.g. `base::subset`), and very extensively in the tidyverse. The special sauce here isn't `desc`, but `arrange`.

Comment: The Book "Advanced R" Chapter on MetaProgramming provides a very good overview of NSE see: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/ . This is the resource I used to understand R and how code like arrange(monkeys, brain_size) actually works.

Comment: [This 5-min video by Hadley is a perfect way to start with tidy evaluation in R](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nERXS3ssntw)

Comment: The `desc` within `arrange` refers to descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dplyr` verbs expect you to input a data frame and will evaluate the column names unquoted. The functions will first look in your data for a column with that name (unquoted), then look in the global environment if there wasn't a match. The `with()` function in base R function similarly accepts unquoted column names `with(mpg, mean(displ))`

`desc()` is another `dplyr` verb and is meant to modify columns within `arrange()`. Note the savings:

```
my_long_table_name <- mpg

my_long_table_name[order(my_long_table_name$displ, decreasing = TRUE),]

my_long_table_name %>% 
  arrange(desc(displ))
```